# Monogame - creating a player

Tags: c#, textures, monogame

after some fine-tuning on my game's GUI I am finally ready to begin with the gameplay. But that's a tall order. My game will be something like a 2D platformer with RPG elements like collecting armor, helmets, weapons etc. So with that in mind I begun thinking about a way to create my player. First, I thought a single `Player` class would do the job for me but since I want to equip the armor/helmet I've acquired, I quickly abandoned this concept.

Next I got another idea. I could have the player's `Head`, `Arms` and `Legs` to be different classes and each of them drawing its own texture, respectively. So I can swap between different armor/helmet sprites for each of the body parts. But that would seem pretty complex to implement... or not?

Could I have a code example on how you would do this? Which path you would take if you are in my stead? Single `Player` class or different body parts classes? If the latter, how would you hook them so that it all looks like a single sprite?

Comment: Welcome.  _"Could I have a code example on how you would do this?"_ - we're not here for this sadly.   You might want to check out [gamedev](http://gamedev.net).

Comment: Usually you start with gameplay first as it's much more complex than the UI. ;-)

Comment: Well at least could you tell me which concept would be correct? I don't even know where to start from :/

Comment: A body part is a body part, an armor is equipped on top of a body part. How about have a `Player` class, and each body part classes, `Head`, `Arm`, `Leg` and, each body part has a `Equipment`? Sure you can swap heads, but different characters have different heads and they also look different in different helmets

Answer (score 0):

Armor/helmet  should be part of the character status as it could be Health points. If you get hit your HP goes down and if your character collides with a helmet item then you should flag that status into your player object and render your character accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [game component pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) (link is a very good read).

You probably want the player class still be the main base of the character, and have armor/clothing components that draw on top of the character.

The player class can then "have" the components and draw accordingly, add HP or other logic you like etc. A component could "break" and disappear etc.